# Ubercart change product image thumbnail in cart view to a different field

Tags: entities, ubercart

When you install ubercart, there is a product image field that is used by default. The field is labeled uc_product_image. I decided not to use this field for different reasons, but now I notice that none of the images for products are showing in the cart as thumbnails. I found and changed the field in the views I could, but I can't find where to change it in the actual cart.

Any help on where or how to change this will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use form_alter hook to change the display.